# Change "?" in URL when FORM send for "&"

Tags: php, forms, get

I have a form:

```
<form action="search" method="GET">
  <input name="q" type="search">
</form>
```

This works correctly:

```
http://localhost/buscar&q=product+red
```

But I can not get this url since the form is sent with "?":

```
http://localhost/buscar?q=product+red
```

Is there any way to receive the GET variable without "?"

Comment: You can rewrite the url to remove the `?` and you can make it look like, for example, `http://localhost/buscar/foo`.

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there a reason for you to want to remove `?`? Please, elaborate on the issue.

Comment: It should be with the `?`, do you have some htaccess rewrite rules or similar that might interfere with it?